# Equivalent of nfsstat -m on older kernel

Tags: nfs, sles

On my SLES 10, SLES 11, and CentOS 6 servers, I'm able to list information about each NFS mount via `nfsstat -m`, e.g.:

```
/usr/local from nfssrv1:/vol/foo
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=blah,mountvers=3,mountport=4046,mountproto=udp,addr=blah
```

We've got some older SLES 9 servers running kernel 2.6.5, and they report back "invalid option -m" when I try that command, so its not supported on the older nfs clients.  How can I find out what flags are being used on these servers?

My goal is to compare the default mount options between servers to troubleshoot some NFS issues in our environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `/proc/mounts`.

```
# grep nfs /proc/mounts
nas-0-0:/export/storage /storage nfs rw,vers=3,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,soft,intr,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,addr=nas-0-0 0 0
```

Comment: Just `mount` by itself shows some flags, but /proc/mounts has more info.